# Application-priority based automatic bandwidth distribution in Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, bandwidth

Whenever my browser wants to download data, I want it to be granted as much of the bandwidth as it wants, while other applications must do with the leftover bandwidth; and when the browser is not transferring any data, other applications could be given the bandwidth. Something like the process priority in Windows task manager. Any method/software to accomplish this automatically?

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of software titles like [**NetLimiter:**](http://www.netlimiter.com/index.php)  [image]
and [**NetBalancer:**](http://www.seriousbit.com/netbalancer/) [image]

Both applications do exactly as you want, but they're not freeware. NetBalancer unregistered version may be of some help despite the limitations:

> The unregistered version is limited to a maximum of 3 process priorities/limits and 3 rules at a time. Since version 6.1 all other limits have been removed

However, if you use WinXP you are lucky, since there's still a freeware named [**TrafficShaperXP**](http://bandwidthcontroller.com/trafficShaperXp.html). Another way of traffic shaping/balancing is your ADSL's router QoS menu which is an entire diffenent approach & topic.